# Salesforce Report on Profiles, Record Types and Page Layouts

Tags: visualforce, reporting, profile, page-layout, record-type

I am an admin and have a request for a report that shows, Profiles, record types and Page Layout assignments. This does not appear to be a report I can pull directly from Salesforce. Any ideas?

Thanks
T

Answer (score 0):

There is no such standard solution for this. Here is the ideas raised:-

1. https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVtnUAF/reporting-on-which-page-layouts-are-used-by-which-profiles

the other solution would be doing a custom development to have report shown in custom page.